# Having trouble reading enum from JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, enums

I have a project regarding a coupon system. One of my beans has an enum. When trying to read it from the database using resultSet, I get an error.

Since enum is not supported I was trying to use this method:

```
Category.valueOf(resultSet.getString(3))
```

The exception I get is, as has been already done before the close vote:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant coupon.beans.Category.4
at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
at coupon.beans.Category.valueOf(Category.java:1)
at coupon.dbdao.CouponsDBDAO.getOneCoupon(CouponsDBDAO.java:122)
at coupon.Program.main(Program.java:32)
```

My enum Class

```
public enum Category {

Food, Electricity, Restaurant, Vacation, Hotel

}
```

My method according to the bean:

```
public Coupon getOneCoupon(int couponID) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

    Coupon result = null;

    try {

        PreparedStatement statement = 
        connection.prepareStatement(GET_ONE_COUPON);
            statement.setInt(1, couponID);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            result = new Coupon(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getInt(2), Category.valueOf(resultSet.getString(3)),
                    resultSet.getString(4), resultSet.getString(5), resultSet.getDate(6), resultSet.getDate(7),
                    resultSet.getInt(8), resultSet.getDouble(9), resultSet.getString(10));

    } finally {
        pool.restoreConnection(connection);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**The code I use to get this ERROR:**

```
Coupon c1 = coupon.getOneCoupon(3);
        System.out.println(c1);
```

**What might of caused the problem:**

```
statement.setInt(2, coupon.getCategory().ordinal() + 1);
```

Comment: If you just get the string and print it out, what value causes this error?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with case sensitivity. First I would print the result of column 3 in the result set, to see if this is a value in your enum.

Comment: I tried fixing the case sensitivity issue in various ways. however, I get the same issue

Comment: @StefanBicher - No, it's not because of case. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971104/10819573).

Comment: It looks like the data base is storing "4" instead of the fourth string representation of your enum.

Comment: This Question cannot be properly solved because you have not provided a complete example. Edit your Question to do so, and the Question can be reopened.

Comment: With the debugging details and in view of the comments, it is fairly obvious: you put the ordinals into your database, but expect the string literals to be present. This kind of error is quite frequent, and experienced users (those who had the opportunity to make this kind of error at least once before) will recognize it whit a glance.

Comment: @BasilBourque - IMO, the error, `No enum constant coupon.beans.Category.4` is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

The **root cause of the problem** is that `resultSet.getString(3)` is returning `4`.

If you try to execute the following line

```
System.out.println(Category.valueOf("4"));
```

you will get an exception, `... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Category.4 ...`

It is because you do not have a constant named as `4`, in your enum definition. In fact, you can not have an enum constant named `4` because the name of an enum constant should conform to the [naming rules for variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

### How to get enum constant using ordinal?

If you want to get an enum constant using its ordinal value, you can use `Category.values()[the-ordinal-vale]` e.g. the following line

```
System.out.println(Category.values()[4]);
```

will return `HOTEL` for the enum defined below.

```
public enum Category {
    FOOD, ELECTRICITY, RESTAURANT, VACATION, HOTEL
}
```

### A side note:

In order to prevent any problem due to case-mismatch, I recommend you use [UPPERCASE for enum constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) as shown above, and pass uppercased `resultSet.getString(3)` to `Category.valueOf` as shown below:

```
Category.valueOf(resultSet.getString(3).toUpperCase())
```

Comment: I have tried that. Still same issue tho.

Comment: @FastacaGirasol - I've updated the answer highlighting the root cause of the problem.

Comment: If resultSet.getString(3) returns 4, resultSet.getString(3).toUpperCase() still will return 4.

Comment: Well after trying to add a new coupon to my data base. then trying to get that coupon the I get the same exception only now it says "No enum constant Category.1". I have checked the correct order according to the CTOR and it seems to be right.

Comment: @GyroGearloose - Yes, that's correct but here, the case is not the root cause of the problem. I've recommended the UPPERCASE name as a prevention, not as a cure.

Comment: I think I came to the root of the problem but I am not sure. could this syntax be a problem : "statement.setInt(2, coupon.getCategory().ordinal() + 1);". I think using ordinal to write to db could cause this problem? if so, how can I fix this?

Comment: @FastacaGirasol obviously so, you save 1,2, etc. to your db, but expect strings like "Food, Electricity, Restaurant, Vacation, Hotel" in return.

Comment: @FastacaGirasol - How are column#2 and column#3 related?

Answer (score 0):

Not what you are explicitly asking, but hopefully helpful to your problem:

you can simulate an enum by creating an auxiliary table in your database, containing entries "Food, Electricity, Restaurant, Vacation, Hotel", let your primary table point to that and add a foreign constraint to that.

Doing this will be (slightly) different depending on what database you are using.

This way, no "illegal" value can be referenced.

In view of the comments made since, it looks like  your database stores the ordinals of the enum values, but your query assumes their names.

Still, you should amend your code (once you figured out where the bull**** comes from) to throw a readable exception.

Edit in view of the unrightful closing:

With the debugging details and in view of the comments, it is fairly obvious: you put the ordinals into your database, but expect the string literals to be present.

Such kinds of error is quite frequent, and experienced users (those who had the opportunity to make this kind of error at least once before) will recognize it whit a glance.

If you use

> statement.setInt(2, coupon.getCategory().ordinal() + 1);

to store the value, you should use

> "yourCategory".values()[ -1]